# Amount of enantiomers

Tags: organic-chemistry

[image: Example molecule]

I got a question about this molecule, and I'm not sure how to answer it. I know that this one has 4 chiral C-atoms, but I can't seem to get the number of enantiomers right. I know that the formula for the amount of enantiomers is $2^{n-1}$, with $n$ being the amount of chiral centers, which is $4$. So that makes an amount of $8$ enantiomers. But that's not what it says in the answer.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Try making combinations of R and S nomenclature on each carbon atom and see the distinct cases

Comment: The formula is useless if you don't know when to use it. And that formula only works if there some level of symmetry in a linear molecule. Frankly, you will find formulas of this type to be less helpful in organic chemistry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compound in question is called D-galactose in carbohydrate chemistry. It has 4 chiral centers (C2, C3, C4, & C5): Thus, stereochemistry of them are $(2R,3S,4S,5R)$. The rule is if a compound has $n$ chiral centers, then it has maximum total of $2^n$ possible stereoisomers, if it does not have any symmetry. D-galactose does not have any symmetry within the molecule (*e.g.*, It would have symmetry if aldehyde group, $\ce{-CHO}$ has been reduced to $\ce{-CH2OH}$). Thus, four chiral centers of D-galactose are accounted for a total of 16 stereoisomers ($2^4$). If you draw them all, you would find they are collection of 8 pairs of enantiomers as:

> {$(2R,3S,4S,5R)$, $(2S,3R,4R,5S)$}
>
> {$(2R,3R,4S,5R)$, $(2S,3S,4R,5S)$}
>
> {$(2R,3S,4R,5R)$, $(2S,3R,4S,5S)$}
>
> {$(2R,3S,4S,5S)$, $(2S,3R,4R,5R)$}
>
> {$(2S,3S,4S,5R)$, $(2R,3R,4R,5S)$}
>
> {$(2R,3R,4R,5R)$, $(2S,3S,4S,5S)$}
>
> {$(2S,3R,4S,5R)$, $(2R,3S,4R,5S)$}
>
> {$(2R,3R,4S,5S)$, $(2S,3S,4R,5R)$}.

That make maximum total of 8 pairs of enantiomers, meaning $2^3 = 2^{4-1} = 2^{n-1}$, where $n$ is number of chiral centers. Therefore, your formula should have been for pair of enanthiomers.

Comment: That was very helpful, I understand now.

Comment: @Guido If you are happy with the answer, feel free to [accept](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it:)